# beforeshowday not working in datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

beforeshowday option not working in datetimepicker I tried below code. I tried by adding simple alert in beforeshowday function but it not working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
const current = new Date();
const prior = new Date().setDate(current.getDate() - 30);
var active_dates = ["03/02/2023","03/03/2023"];
$("#purchase_date").datetimepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii:ss',
    autoclose: true,
    todayBtn: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    //startDate: new Date(prior),
    //endDate: '+0d',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
    beforeShowDay: function(date){alert();
        var d = date;
        var curr_date = d.getDate();
        var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
        var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
        var formattedDate = curr_month + "/" + curr_date + "/" + curr_year

        if ($.inArray(formattedDate, active_dates) != -1){
           return {
              classes: 'activeClass'
           };
        }
        return;
    },
        
});
});
```

Comment: Please specify *which* (of the 1000s) `datetimepicker` you are using, ideally with a CDN link and/or a website.  You've tagged [jquery-ui] but that only has a datepicker without time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve]. This appears to be the 'DateTimePicker' and not the jQuery DatePicker. Please ensure that you are using the right tags and libraries.